# Constant term in a minimal polynomial is a scalar, but not so when polynomial is composed with linear transformation.

Tags: linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

So if the minimal polynomial of some linear transformation is say $\ \mu (x) = x^2+x+2$, then if we put in a matrix $\ A$ in for $\ X$ instead, we would write this is as $\ \mu(A) = A^2 + A + 2I$ with the identity matrix multiplying our scalar. Obviously we can put any linear transformation in for the variable x using the definition that $\ f^2(v) = f(f(v))$, but in this case what would we put next to our scalar? I have a feeling it would be the identity transformation.

A specific example: Say we have $\ f(B) = AB $ for some fixed matrix A. What would be $\ \mu(f)$ in my example? A solution to a problem I am working on (past exam) would suggest that $\ \mu(f(B)) = A^2B + AB + 2B$. I am confused as to why my 2 was transformed to a 2B.

Comment: I think you meant $\mu(f)(B)$, since $\mu(f(B))=\mu(AB)=ABAB+AB+2I$. But $\mu(f)=f^2+f+2I$, and this sends $B\mapsto A^2B+AB+B$.

Comment: I saw my lecturer today and this is exactly how he explained it, this is the specific point I was confused about thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We are using an evaluation morphism at $a$, $\phi_a$, which goes from $K[x]$ to a commutative unital algebra $A$ in such a way that

- $\phi_a(x)=a$.
- $\phi_a(1)=1_A$.
- $\phi_a$ is a linear map and a ring homomorphism.

What we have here is evaluation from $(K[x],+,\cdot)$ to $A:=(K[f],+,\circ)$, where $f$ is a linear endomorphism of the vector space $V$ and the product $\circ$ is the composition. For this algebra we get $1_A=\text{id}$, i.e., the identity map is the identity element (because the product is composition).

Then, after evaluation of the polynomial $p$ at the linear endomorphism $f$, you get a new linear endomorphism $p(f)$, in which the independent term of $p$ generates a multiple of the identity map.